# Concatenating each element of a data frame in R

Tags: r, merge, concatenation

I would like to concatenate each element of a data frame with the respective element of an equally sized data frame. Here's an example of two data frames I need to combine:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      X     Y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     9     5
2     5    10
3     1     4

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  X     Y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 (10%) (5%) 
2 (3%)  (9%) 
3 (22%) (9%)
```

And here would be the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  X       Y      
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 9 (10%) 5 (5%) 
2 5 (3%)  10 (9%)
3 1 (22%) 4 (9%)
```

Here is the data for the first two objects:

```
library(tidyverse)

structure(list(X = c(9, 5, 1), Y = c(5, 10, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(X = c("(10%)", "(3%)", "(22%)"), Y = c("(5%)", 
"(9%)", "(9%)")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `df1[] <- Map(paste, df1, df2)` should do the trick

Comment: Or, the tidy way would be to use `purrr::pmap_df(list(df1, df2), paste)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map2_df(df1, df2, str_c, sep=" ")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  X       Y      
#   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 9 (10%) 5 (5%) 
#2 5 (3%)  10 (9%)
#3 1 (22%) 4 (9%)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your data above, I tried the following with good luck.

Note: I renamed variables to make the bind and unite calls a bit more clear:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat1 <- structure(list(W = c(9, 5, 1), X = c(5, 10, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                               -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dat2 <- structure(list(Y = c("(10%)", "(3%)", "(22%)"), Z = c("(5%)", 
                                                      "(9%)", "(9%)")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))

dat3 <- cbind(dat1, dat2) %>% 
        unite('X2', c('W','Y')) %>% 
        unite('Y2', c('X','Z'))
```

Comment: This works great! I went with akrun's answer because it allows for a more dynamic separator argument.